# Why won't my do-while loop continue looping?

Tags: c++, do-while

I'm working on creating a menu with error checking and this is what I've come up with, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

char option; // user's entered option will be saved in this variable
int error1 = 0;

 //Displaying Options for the menu
cout << "There are three packages available." << endl;
cout << "Monthly Price - Price per MB for overages (excluding C)" << endl;
cout << "A) $15 - $.06 for each MB after 200 MB." << endl;
cout << "B) $25 - $.02 for each MB after 2,000 MB ( approx. 2 GB)." << endl;
cout << "C) $50 - Unlimited data." << endl;

do //do-while loop starts here
{ 

 //Prompting user to enter an option according to menu
 cout << "Please enter which plan you currently have : ";
 cin >> option;  // taking option value as input and saving in variable "option"

 if(option == 'A' || option == 'a') // Checking if user selected option 1
 {
    cout << "You chose a" << endl;
    error1 = 1;
 }
 else if(option == 'B' || option == 'b') // Checking if user selected option 2
 {
    cout << "You chose b" << endl;
    error1 = 1;
 }
 else if(option == 'C' || option == 'c') // Checking if user selected option 3
 {
    cout << "You chose c" << endl;
    error1 = 1;
 }
 else //if user has entered invalid choice 
 {
   //Displaying error message
   error1 = 0;
   cout << "Invalid Option entered";
 }
 }
while(error1 = 0);  //condition of do-while loop
return 0;
}
```

When typing in an incorrect value, the output will be Invalid Option entered; however, it won't loop back to the beginning and prompt the user for input again.

Why is it doing this?

Comment: change while(error1 = 0); into while(error1 == 0);

Comment: This is just a typo, you assigned instead of checked for equality.

Comment: Turn up the warning levels on your compiler.

Comment: I'll  definitely look into it @ThomasMatthews

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
while(error1 = 0);  //condition of do-while loop
```

into this

```
while(error1 == 0);  //condition of do-while loop
```

in the first option you just assign 0 to `error1` and then `error1` is being tested as boolean which means 0 is FALSE and non-0 is TRUE. So sonce the condition in the `while` is evaluated as FALSE, the loop ends.

Comment: Completely missed this, thanks for being another set of eyes.

Comment: @AugieLuebbers you are welcome. It is a very common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `0` to `error1` inside the `while`, which is always false, so the loop will not repeat. Change `while(error1=0);` to `while(error1==0);`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't catch that!

Answer (score 1):

Just as complement: consider invert the expression thus:

```
while (0 = error1);
```

In this way the compiler will stop you if you forget the additional `=` or confound the assignment with the equal operator

Comment: Hadn't thought of this, but sounds like a good idea. I'll keep it in mind for the future. Thanks @lrleon